# space between text and checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, checkbox

I want to have space between checkbox and the text.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublic" runat="server" Text="Public" Font-Bold="true" />
```

How to get space between checkbox and text. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I need some css format. Thanks.

Comment: Add `style=margin-left: 5px` to the label or `style=margin-right: 5px` to the checkbox

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublic" runat="server" Text="Public" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="mycheckbox" />
```

In stylesheet.css

```
.mycheckbox input[type="checkbox"] 
{ 
    margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: I believe since the label is to the *right* of the text, the label needs to have a `margin-left` applied to space it away from the checkbox. I tried both and only `margin-left: 5px` worked as the OP question needed.

Comment: @atconway - the class, when applied to the `asp:Checkbox` control, with a selector for input type of `checkbox`, actually gets applied to the actual input control, the checkbox, not its label.  tutts' use of `margin-right` is correct.

Comment: Very simple elegant solution! I've added this to my site.css!

Answer (score 5):

A late reply, but hopefully helpful to someone else looking for a solution. You can "quick-and-dirty" add space by embedding non-breaking spaces in the text property value. The advantage is that you can do this for controls that are exceptions to the styles applied elsewhere without having to create a new style sheet for just one control. For example:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myCheckBox" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Check this to subscribe" />
```

Comment: this is the only answer that helped me with something i have put multiple hours into, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a style for the label:

```
label {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

However it will affect the header labels so I also created a style as well:

```
.lheader {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #1ca795;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It worked perfectly on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&nbsp` before the text

in case for example text is generated like this:
`Text='<%# Eval("SubCatName")%>'`

do it like this:
`Text='<%#"&nbsp"+Eval("SubCatName")%>'`

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublic" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true" />&nbsp;MyText
```

Or maybe just like that:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPublic" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Public" Font-Bold="true" />
```

`&nbsp;` is a single space in html

Comment: HTML encoding spaces isn't good practise, css should be used and applied to the checkbox via CssClass attribute.

Comment: Exactly! What if the checkbox was to the RIGHT of the text? Or... ??

Comment: Somehow, I could not get the favorite answer to work. Guess I'm too noob with CSS still. This solved the need in a direct way.